# How to set number of loops on username list "for loop" and give pause every send

Tags: python

How can I set the number of "for loops" based on a list of usernames?

I'm planning to create a username checker and set the number of username checks in each send and give a delay. For example, let's say I have a list of 50 users in a text file, like this:

```
Johnsonkn89ooo8ii
Kontoldowo525ywy2yyy
Jembotsenekusertai
```

I want to send 5 API requests to check 5 usernames. After 5 usernames are successfully checked it will pause for 10 seconds, then check the next 5 usernames, until it reaches the end.

This is my code so far:

```
list = "list.txt"
mod = "r+"
op = open(list, mod).readlines()

for fr in op:

    #I want to set the number of usernames in a single send and set the pause each send is given a 10 second delay

    x = fr.rstrip ("\n")
    api_check_username(x)
```

Comment: you could use `for x in range(0, len(op), 5)` to get values 0, 5, 10, etc. and then you can get `op[x:x+5]` to work only with 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it should be sufficient to enumerate through the names and based on modulo of the index add a delay like this (this is a quick 'n' dirty code that sleeps at the beginning too, this is just to illustrate the basic idea):

```
import time

delay = 10
send_amount = 5

list = "list.txt"
mod = "r+"
op = open(list, mod).readlines()

for i, fr in enumerate(op):

    #I want to set the number of usernames in a single send and set the pause each send is given a 10 second delay

    x = fr.rstrip ("\n")
    api_check_username(x)

    if i % send_amount == 0:
        time.sleep(delay)
```